# What is wrong in my CSS/Javascript drop down menu test code?

Tags: javascript, css, debugging, menu

I am attempting to use a combination of CSS and JS to create a navigation menu.  What is supposed to happen is that, when mousing over a main topic (menu level 0), a list of subtopics appear, and they disappear as soon as you mouse over a different main topic.  The method I tried is to have a JS function change the "display" property of the element containing the list of subtopics, between "none" and "block".  The subtopic list is in a div block that is nested within the div block containing the main topic.

To clarify what is happening, I set borders of different colors around the different element types.  The problem seems to be that the nested subtopic div block is not really nested, but is rendered below the main top div block, as shown by the fact that the green border surrounding the subtopic block is external to the blue border surrounding the main topic block.  I am testing with both Chrome and Firefox, and the behavior is the same, so there must be something that I don't understand and am doing wrong.

I see that there are numerous questions about drop-down menus, and I would be happy to be pointed to a better way of achieving what I want.  But I would also like to understand what I am doing wrong in my example, to further my understanding of CSS and JS.

Comment: I did something similar once, also with pure CSS. Are you doing this with a tutorial at hand?

Comment: This is probably much easier and cleaner to do with pure CSS - except the already-open submenu on page load.

Comment: The challenge, often, is finding an example or tutorial that is appropriate.  I started out with one, and then tried to make it fit to do something somewhat different.  Anyway, I think I'm on a viable path, with the answer and comments given below.  I'd still like to understand about block elements and nested div's, which is the only reason I couldn't get my original code to work, however inelegant it may be.  I thought that enclosing an element within a <div></div> would mean that it was included (and expanded the size, if need be) within the div's block, but that apparently is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcurran/5P4Kd/) of a menu with submenus done only with css.  It's not exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but it should get you on the right path.

It's not much of a stretch from here to align them vertically, show one div on page load, or whatever.

I commented the css so you can see how little code is really needed for a basic implementation.

**EDIT**
[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/5P4Kd/5/) an updated fiddle that I think does what you need it to.  It slides content down when opening a sub meun on hover.

Comment: Good, so far, and much simpler than my JS/CSS method, but there is still a problem.  I deleted the "float: left;" from the "navbar li" style, to make the buttons list vertically, which is the default behavior for a list.  But then the drop-down menu covers up the following list item, where I had hoped to push everything down so that the all main topics were still visible.  It actually looks like the same issue I was trying to deal with originally - the block for the main topic (in this case, the top level list item) does not expand to contain the list of sub-topics (the nested list).  Ideas?

Comment: You want to push all of the lower elements down when an upper element is expanded?  Sorry, I didn't realize that aspect of it. In that case I would put thee i in a jquery ui accordion. That's probably the simplest implementation that will do what you want.

Comment: Or add a margin to the li's (currently it is set to zero). That won't push everything down, but it will slide the sub menus over so they don't hide the other content.

Comment: Can't do the margin thing -- this is for a limited-width nav bar at the right side of the page.

Never heard of the jquery UI accordion, but it looks pretty good.  The only catch, in the one example I have looked at, is that the behavior happens on mouse-click rather than mouse-over, but maybe I'll be able to change that.  It'll take me some time to go through the example (http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/exactly-how-to-create-a-custom-jquery-accordion/)  and understand it.

Comment: yes, you can set it to open on hover instead of click by setting event: 'mouseover'.  That tutorial is pretty involved, btw.  It looks nice, but you may want to start with a basic implementation  and work in the extras later only if you need them.  The 'view source' link just below the accordion demo @ jqueryui.com shows you exactly how to code it.  You can also import one of their pre-rolled themes, so you won't have to mess with css at all:)

Comment: @user1639379 check out the updated fiddle in my edited answer above

Comment: Sheesh, I'm not sure I want to pursue this -- looks like a significant learning experience just to figure out how to do anything in JQuery, and even the "simple" demo seems to assume you already know JQuery, AND it would increase our server bandwidth significantly.  It is making me rethink how important this functionality is to me!  I may go back to the CSS method you first suggested (fortunately, I establish the requirements as well as implement them, so I can decide to make the trade-off).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it **is** possible to have a CSS-only solution that does exactly what I was aiming for, namely a list which, when an entry is moused over, expands that entry with a sub-list.  My worst problem was that I was including "position: absolute;" in the style, which prevented the containing element from expanding to accommodate the newly displayed sub-list.  Following is a complete code example, which has been tested in Chrome and Firefox and validated by validome.org:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<!-- DropDownExpandMenuExample2\TestWEMenus.html - 2012-09-01 -->

<head>
<title>Test of menu styles</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>
<meta name="author" content=" Bruce Bon "></meta>
<style type="text/css">

div.navcontainer{
    font:           10pt/14pt 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background:     transparent;
    width:          220px;
    margin-left:    0px;
    /* position:      absolute; top: 210px; left: 660px;*/
    position:       absolute; top: 20px; left: 660px;
    padding-left:   10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    color:          #22657F;
    z-index:        10;        /* make sure in front */
    border-left:    2px solid #BB77FF;
    }

/* main topic styles */
ul#navmaintopiclist {
    margin:     0;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding:    0;
    }
ul#navmaintopiclist li {
    font-size:        14px;
    padding-top:      5px;
    padding-bottom:   5px;
    font-weight:      bold;
    list-style:       none;
    }
ul#navmaintopiclist li a {
    display:         block;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

/* Add the link and hover effects */
ul#navmaintopiclist li:link    {
    color: #333388; text-decoration:none; }
ul#navmaintopiclist li:visited {
    color: #6633AA; text-decoration:none; }
ul#navmaintopiclist li:hover   {
    color: #5555BB;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

ul#navmaintopiclist li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    }

/* Hide the subtopics, set subtopic size, etc */
ul.subtopiclist {
    display:          none; 
    background-color: #BBFFBB;
    width:            180px;        /* Width to help Opera out */
    position:         relative;
    left:             0px;
    }

ul#navmaintopiclist li ul li {
    background:       transparent;
    list-style-type:  none;
    font-family:      'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:        14px;
    letter-spacing:   -1px;
    font-weight:      bold;
    margin-left:      -20px;
    }

</style>

</head>


<body>

<div class="navcontainer">

  <ul id='navmaintopiclist'>

    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>

    <li><a href="index.html">Healthy Mind</a>
      <ul class='subtopiclist'>
        <li>Stress and Anxiety</li>
        <li>Emotional Freedom</li>
        <li>Self-Hypnosiss</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="index.html">Healthy Body</a>
      <ul class='subtopiclist'>
        <li>SubOne</li>
        <li>SubOne</li>
        <li>SubOne</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

</ul>


</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: in that case you can also mark the question as resolved - right?